# How can i position two Views in left and right?

Tags: css, react-native

I want to position two views on of them left and the another in right, but the right view disssapear when i aplied the style like this:

```
 return (
        <View style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <View style={{ float: 'left' }}>
                <Avatar.Icon
                    size={iconSize}
                    name="md-beer" type="ionicon"
                    color="blue"
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#00aced',
                        width: customAvtardimension,
                        height: customAvtardimension,
                    }}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, fontSize: 16, lineHeight: 30, color: '#1D2359', textAlign: 'right' }}>
                <Button icon="camera" >
                </Button>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
```

why does not work? my mistake is in the css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should in your style prop use `flexDirection: 'row'` to set views next to each other

Comment: This is the solution. With getting items in the same row, you can adjust the space that you need between the elements.

Comment: why for the left element i need to use 'width'? without that it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is the right solution. This is what your code would look like.

```
return (
        <View style={{ width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <View style={{ float: 'left' }}>
                <Avatar.Icon
                    size={iconSize}
                    name="md-beer" type="ionicon"
                    color="blue"
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#00aced',
                        width: customAvtardimension,
                        height: customAvtardimension,
                    }}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, fontSize: 16, lineHeight: 30, color: '#1D2359', textAlign: 'right' }}>
                <Button icon="camera" >
                </Button>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
```

You can add additional styling for spacing, using `justifyContent` property.